# Debug dockerized Django application running Uvicorn - ASGI on VSCode?

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, uvicorn

I'm trying to run [debugpy](https://pypi.org/project/debugpy/) in attach mode to debug on VScode a dockerized Django app. With the following configuration on `launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "pathMappings": [{
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "/app"
            }],
            "port": 9999,
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been able to attach correctly to it adding the following section on the `manage.py` file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

    # debugpy configuration
    from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG:
        if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") or os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
            import debugpy

            debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 9999))
    ...
```

The Django `Dockerfile` is launching the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python manage.py migrate

exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And I'm exposing the ports 8000 and 9999 running the docker image. So far so good.

What I'm trying to do now is enable the same support for the ASGI application running under [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python manage.py migrate

exec uvicorn config.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --reload --reload-include '*.html'
```

`asgi.py`

```py
"""
ASGI config for Suite-Backend project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/asgi/

"""
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

# This allows easy placement of apps within the interior
# suite_backend directory.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR / "suite_backend"))

# If DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is unset, default to the local settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

# This application object is used by any ASGI server configured to use this file.
django_application = get_asgi_application()
```

Even forcing debugpy to listen on port 9999 I'm unable to attach to it. I can't provide you any logs but I think that running the VSCode debugger with "Python: Django" configuration cannot simply find an available listener and just dies.

Do you have any clue or suggestion on how to setup this environment properly? I've been searching for about an hour but couldn't find any resources on the matter.

Comment: Have you tried to attach debugpy in your asgi.py file exactly like you did with your manage.py file?

Comment: I did try that but I was adding it with the same check condition in it `os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") or os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN")`. Removing this check actually works! Now I'm wondering how can I implement the same logic but in ASGI. Because of course I cannot use `RUN_MAIN` nor `WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same configuration in your `asgi.py` file as you did with the `manage.py` file, like below:

```
"""
ASGI config for Suite-Backend project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/asgi/

"""
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

if settings.DEBUG:
    if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") or os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
        import debugpy

        debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 9999))
        debugypy.wait_for_client()

# This allows easy placement of apps within the interior
# suite_backend directory.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR / "suite_backend"))

# If DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is unset, default to the local settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

# This application object is used by any ASGI server configured to use this file.
django_application = get_asgi_application()
```

You can use `debugpy.wait_for_client()` [option mentioned here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy#waiting-for-the-client-to-attach). This would ensure attaching debugpy once.

Also, instead of reading values from env using `os.environ`, I'll recommend using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) package that takes care of parsing booleans and provides additional capabilities.

Comment: The main reason to use `RUN_MAIN` or `WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN` envs is to prevent the debugpy channel listener to be restarted everytime file changes are detected (e.g. running uvicorn with `--reload` option). This is used by Django itself as explained here https://programmersought.com/article/49721374106

So I was looking for something similar in uvicorn but it doesn't seem to be anything.

Comment: I think you can use the `wait_for_client()` method. I just updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That is used to wait until a client attaches, I don't see any utility for this use case scenario sadly.

Comment: I tried to find an equivalent env var in the uvicorn, but it doesn't state any.  I think one way to go about it can be to set a custom env var and then for the first run it can have a true value and then you set it to false after initializing your django application. So, in case of a restart, you'll find it false and avoid attaching debugpy again.